# Setting a ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I'm working on a `Django` application feature where a restaurant can add extras to his meals.

So I set an `extra` model with two attributes (extra_n: extra name and extra_price : extra price)

Then I associated this model to the `meal` model.

***models.py***

```
class Extra(models.Model):
    extra_n = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    extra_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.extra_n

class Meal(models.Model):  
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ForeignKey(MealCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='meal_images/', blank=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    extras = models.ManyToManyField(Extra)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

I'm having a confusion. The goal is to create extras for each meal. Those extras are going to be associated to one meal and no other.

while checking on the django admin I find that whenever I add an extra, it's associated to all meals.

Can anyone please help figure out the problem ?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that it is associated to all meals when checking the admin? As far as i can tell the models look quite ok to me...

Comment: Having an extra field on the meal form, when I check I find that the extras added for other meals are already added to my current meal @BernhardVallant

Comment: Are you sure? If you use Django's default many to many widget it will show all available extras, but not as "selected"/"chosen"...

Comment: @BernhardVallant and how could I show just the 'selected/chosen' ?